# How can I select all the record having a bigint field starting with a specific digit?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem.

I havve write this simple JOIN query:

```
select a.nome, a.cognome from Banker b
INNER JOIN Anagrafica a
ON b.AnagraficaID = a.ID
INNER JOIN Polizza p
ON p.BankerID = b.ID
WHERE p.ID LIKE "7%"
```

My problem is on the last **WHRE** clause. I want that the where condition is that all the returned records have to start with the digit **7** but I obtain this error message:

```
 14:59:07  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 207, SQL State: S0001]  Invalid column name '7%'.
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

I think that it could depend because the **ID** field of the **Polizza** table is a **bigint** and not a **varchar**.

So how can I implement this thing on this type of field? I need that it return only record having the the **ID** field of the **Polizza** table that starts with **7**

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server uses single quotes to wrap strings

```
select a.nome, a.cognome from Banker b
INNER JOIN Anagrafica a
ON b.AnagraficaID = a.ID
INNER JOIN Polizza p
ON p.BankerID = b.ID
WHERE p.ID LIKE '7%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to cast ID and remove double quotes from "7%"

```
WHERE CAST(p.ID AS VARCHAR(30)) LIKE '7%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CAST

```
select a.nome, a.cognome from Banker b
INNER JOIN Anagrafica a
 ON b.AnagraficaID = a.ID
INNER JOIN Polizza p
  ON p.BankerID = b.ID
WHERE CAST(p.ID AS VARCHAR(50))LIKE '7%'
```